# Assert value for key in cookie dict

Tags: python, cookies, automated-tests, splinter

I've just started working with python test automation, and I'm trying to assert that a certain cookie with a certain value is being set when clicking on a certain button. I'm automating tests using splinter, and so far I have this:

```
cookie_bar = browser.find_link_by_text('Yes')
manage_cookies = browser.find_link_by_text('Manage cookies')
    if not manage_cookies:
        if cookie_bar:
            browser.find_link_by_text('Yes').first.click()
        else:
            browser.find_link_by_text('Hide this message').first.click()
    if manage_cookies:
            browser.find_link_by_text('Manage cookies').first.click()
            browser.driver.switch_to_window(browser.windows[-1].name)
            browser.find_by_text('Accept Cookies').first.click()
            browser.driver.switch_to_window(browser.windows[-1].name)
            cookies_list = browser.cookies.all()
```

The "browser.cookies.all()" method returns a dict of {'cookie1': 'value1', 'cookie2': 'value2', etc.}; I'm trying to assert that "cookie1" comes back with value "value1", but so far nothing I've tried has worked, as they all come with some sort of "unhashable" error:

```
assert ['cookie1' == 'value1'] in cookies_list # TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
assert [{'cookie1': 'value1'}] in cookies_list # TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
assert {'cookie1': 'value1'} in cookies_list # TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
assert {'cookie1', 'value1'} in cookies_list #TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Now, I've never worked with python before, so maybe it's something really simple that's escaping me, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. I can assert them individually, but what I really need is, in the simplest terms:

```
assert 'cookie1' with value 'value1' in cookies_list
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saying that `browser.cookies.all()` return a dict, therefore, you should use it as a dict and not as a list.

For example you can do:

```
assert cookies_list.get('cookie1', None) == 'value1'
```

Find some more info about dictionary [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

To check multiples values:
Create another dict we the expected values:

```
expected = {'cookie1': 'value1', 'cookie2': 'value2'}
```

Edit to improve answer:
And then iterate on all keys of the dict.

```
for key in expected.keys():
    assert cookies_list.get(key, None) == expected[key]
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Is it possible to do it as a list of keys and values? As in "assert cookies_list.get('cookie1', 'cookie2') == 'value1', 'value2'?

Comment: @RagnarOdin I've edited my answer, I hope that this will help you.

Comment: Double the thanks, the improved answer worked like a charm!